# No visible @Interface for 'FBSDKLoginManager' declares the selector 'loginWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:'

Tags: cocoapods, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x, xcode11.3

[Xcode 11.3, Facebook SDK : Version 6.0.0

I'm not able to login with Facebook for my app, and then I updated pod "FBSDKLogin" to Version 6.0.0, the errors in the image came out and made me not able to build app.

Anyone can help me on this, please? Appreciate that, thanks.
[image: IDE screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[This is the first error, I have inserted pod FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EYmF.png)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not any close to be familiar with neither of your tools nor SDKs, but in my PHP IDE I usually see this much of red highlighting and lots of errors when I miss a parenthesis, or put a dot instad of comma, or do any other kind of typo to mess language syntax in any other way.

- Did you check your code for typos?
- Did you check any other
  dependencies of your own for typos or export errors (or any other
  concepts that might override or break interfaces)?
- Did you try
  looking up the **first error** on the screenshot, rather than the
  *last* one (e.g. `Called object type 'id' is not a function or function pointer`)?

Comment: This could have been just a comment.